# Splitting CSV file by two columns

Tags: powershell, csv

Starting with a 500,000 line CSV, I need to split the files by day and hour (the second and third columns). I've tried the modify the group to include the hour and while I see the hour get added to my filename, I get no results in the exported file.

The foreach doing the work:

```
foreach ($group in $data | Group Day,hour) {
  $data | Where-Object { $_.Day -and $_.Hour -eq $group.Name }
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
    foreach {$_.Replace('"','')} | 
    Out-File "$Path\Testfile_$($group.name -replace $regexA, '').csv"
```

Sample Data:

```
Bob,1/27/2012,8:00,Basic,Operations
Charlie,2/3/2012,9:00,Advanced,Production
Bill,3/7/2012,10:00,Advanced,Production
```

Comment: `$data | Where-Object { $_.Day -and $_.Hour -eq $group.Name }` -> `$_.Group` contains all the things in the group, no need to rescan all 500,000 things to try and make up the group again. `$_.Day -and $_.Hour` is not doing what you think, this is a boolean operator and returns `$True` which will never match the group name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could import the CSV, determine the output filename on the fly, and append each record to the matchning file:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' | ForEach-Object {
  $filename = ('output_{0}_{1}.csv' -f $_.Day, $_.Hour) -replace '[/:]'
  $_ | Export-Csv "C:\path\to\$filename" -Append -NoType 
}
```

Note that `Export-Csv -Append` requires PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this method a try when I can reboot to install PSv3

Comment: On earlier versions you could use something like `$_ | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content`. Less elegant (and you'll lose the header), but should work.

Comment: Thanks I've marked this as the answer as it did exactly what I needed done.